# Search files by extension in windows

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-search, file-extension

I want to search only svg files in a folder containing svg and svgz files.
I typed "*svg" in the search bar but I get all the files begining with the svg extension including svgz.

How do I exclude the svgz results?

Comment: I find [this command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13799990/9334297) very efficient for that, otherwise use [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/), it's a fast searching app

Comment: If using PowerShell is an option for you, [How to retrieve recursively any files with a specific extensions in PowerShell?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31049571/1115360) leads to `Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Filter *.svg`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the `NOT` condition. Try the following query:

`*.svg NOT *.svgz`

This will include all `*.svg` results while excluding all `*.svgz` results.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `NOT` command in your Search window... this works in Windows Explorer.

[image: NOT Command Screenshot]

Here is an example that will return `.doc` files but not `.docx` files:

```
*doc NOT *.docx
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Thanks for taking your time to answer this question. It is appreciated. However, please include text versions of any command(s) you use in your answer (not just screenshots). Otherwise, again, thank you!